# Jade template - How to pass a data from View page to Edit page

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express with jade and i have created a table view for the data. When i click edit it should show the data(Plant, Material, Currency etc.) in respective input fields of edit page.

Table View page for data,

```
extends layout

block content
  h1(style='text-align:center')= title
  button(type='submit', onClick='nav()') Add a Material
  script.
    function nav() {
      window.location.href = '/addpage'
    }
    function passvalue(params) {
      console.log(params)
    }
  br
  br
  -var product = data
  div
  table.table.table-hover(border='1', style='width:100%')
    tr
        th Plant
        th Material
        th Currency
        th Rate
        th Options
    tbody
      each value in product
        tr
          td(style='text-align:center')= value.PLANT
          td(style='text-align:left')= value.MATERIAL
          td(style='text-align:left')= value.CURRENCY
          td(style='text-align:right')= value.RATE
          td(style='text-align:left')
            ul
                a(href = '/', 
                onClick = `javascript:alert("Plant :${value.PLANT}, Material : ${value.MATERIAL}, Customer : ${value.CUSTOMER}, Rate : ${value.RATE}, Currency : ${value.CURRENCY}, Price_Unit : ${value.PRICE_UNIT}, Cond_Unit : ${value.COND_UNIT}, Portal_User : ${value.PORTAL_USER}")`
                ) View              
                br
                a(href = '/editpage', onClick = `passvalue(${value})`) Edit
                br
                a(href = '/', onClick = 'javasript:alert("Delete functionality development is in-progress")') Delete
```

Edit page to edit selected data,

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  label(for='plant') Plant:
  input(placeholder = 'Plant Number', id = 'plant')
  br
  br
  div
    label(for='material') Material:
    input(placeholder = 'Material Name')
    br
    br
  div
    label(for='customer') Customer:
    input(placeholder = 'Customer Code')
    br
    br
  div
    label(for='rate') Rate:
    input(placeholder = 'Rate')
    br
    br
  div
    label(for='currency') Currency:
    input(placeholder = 'Currency')
    br
    br
  div
    label(for='price_unit') Price_Unit:
    input(placeholder = 'Price_Unit')
    br
    br
  div
    label(for='cond_unit') Cond_Unit:
    input(placeholder = 'Cond_Unit')
    br
    br
  div
    label(for='portal_user') Portal_User:
    input(placeholder = 'Portal_User')
    br
    br
  div
    button(type='submit') Save
    button(type='submit', onClick = 'nav()') Cancel
    script.
      function nav() {
        window.location.href='/'
      }
```

[Table View page for data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chq5x.png)

[Edit page to edit selected data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oR7C.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This tutorial](https://zellwk.com/blog/crud-express-mongodb/) is one of many good starting points for you in this.

Basically, you need to set up a route for your edit page that takes the ID of the plant as part of the URL, then use it to retrieve the data for that plant.  Feeding the result to the jade template lets it do its work:

```
app.get('/plant/:id', function(req, res){

  // plant id is available here as req.params.id

  if(req.params.id){
    // fetch data for plant with this id
    res.render('edit-plant', data);
  } else {
    // no id given, must be a new plant
    res.render('edit-plant', {});
  }

});
```

Then, on your list page just add the plant id to the href tag of your links:

```
each plant in plants
  a(href= '/plants/' + plant.id)= plant.name
```